# Clipping large IUCN range map vector file to shapefile using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, clip, arcgis-10.4

I'm having trouble clipping my large IUCN species range maps vector file to a southeast asia boundary shapefile. The single vector file consists of many individual species polygons. I've tried eliminating most of the polygons that are non SEA, made sure both shapefiles are in the same projection, and then clip it to SEA boundary shapefile, but i get an error message saying I've generated an empty output. After reading some answers online, I tried repairing geometry but the same issue arise, empty output. I've tried QGIS but that doesn't work either,software crashes.

What could be the problem and how can I solve this?

Comment: What coordinate system(s) are your two datasets in?

Comment: They are in WGS 1984

Comment: When you add both to a Blank Map do they overlap?

Comment: Yes they do overlap

Comment: @PolyGeo any ideas, my friend? would really appreciate if someone could help. The boundary shapefile was gotten from Natural Earth.

Comment: I've already given what I think are the first two things to check and assuming that you repaired the geometry of both I am out of ideas for tonight.

Comment: have you tried in a geodatabase ? Shapefile fails when there are too many vertices.

Comment: @radouxju Hi, I have not, but I'm keen to try it out. Which geodatabase do you suggest I use?

Comment: I would try to export both shapefiles in the same file gdb (inside a feature dataset), and store the result also in this gdb.

Comment: Try [Repair Geometry](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/repair-geometry.htm) first then re-clip it

Comment: @radouxju I think using a file geodatabase is an excellent idea but I don't recall having come across a processing limit when a shapefile has too many vertices. I think I have read that they become unstable at about 500Mb in size.

Comment: @PolyGeo Well, size and number of vertices are linked more than size and number of polygons. And it is usually the size of the .shp file that causes unstability (also if you exceed the number of columns in the .dbf, but this is another issue). That being said, I agree that the issue might more be due to the lack of XY tolerance than the number of vertices (which also advocates for the use of gdb).